# Getting null pointer exception when data read from excel file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

Getting null pointer exception :
verifying the login successful or not.

```
public class Test {
        
    
        private static WebDriver driver; 
        private static XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        private static XSSFSheet sheet;
        private static XSSFCell cell;
        
        public void init() {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
            
        }
        
        public void setExcelFile() throws Exception  {
        File file =new File("TestData.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(file);
        workbook =new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sheet =workbook.getSheetAt(0);  
        }
    @Test
    public void login() {
        cell= sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0);
        DataFormatter dd=new DataFormatter();
        String username= dd.formatCellValue(cell);
        cell= sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
        String password=dd.formatCellValue(cell);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type='text'])[2]")).sendKeys(username);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//button[@type='submit'])[2]")).click();
        Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'My Account')]")).isDisplayed());
    }
```

console Error :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke
> "org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet.getRow(int)" because
> "TestFlipkartDemo.sheet" is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) When you create the TestFlipkartDemo object, the sheet pointer doesn't point to any object.

(2) Your test runner calls your test right after, resulting in you trying to call the method getRow of no object.

You must call the function at (3) before your test runner calls the function at (2).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One of the big reason is you have entered incorrect sheet name or value. Make sure you have you entered correct sheet name i.e. "Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);". Zero (0) means "Sheet 1" of excel source file.